# How to remove old kickstand

Tags: parts, frugal, vintage, replacement, kickstand

I'm trying to cannibalize an old bike but am having trouble removing the kickstand:

[image: Top view of kickstand]
[image: Side view of kickstand]

I've tried screwing the bolt counter-clockwise<sup>†</sup>, which indeed made it looser, but it's not getting loose enough to remove the kickstand; What might I be doing wrong here?-- is there possibly something worn/rusted out which is causing the bolt to not loosen any further?

---

<sup>†</sup> At least I think I turned it counter-clockwise, but I may be remembering wrong. Could it actually loosen by turning it *clockwise* instead?

Comment: Quick google image search for ESGE kickstands and the bolt appears to be very long, and from the image of your kickstand, it looks like you will need to back the bolt out completely (there is no top/bottom plates, the bolt looks to go directly into the kickstand itself).

Comment: Yep, just keep turning counter-clockwise.  It's a long bolt.  (I've removed a number of these and never had trouble with them, unlike some other styles.)

Comment: If it seems to get harder to turn, could be corrosion.  This bolt is pretty exposed on the bottom of the bike, and will see all the road salt and grime.   Try squirting some penetrating oil onto the threads if it gets harder to undo.  Yes, its a normal right-hand thread.

Comment: Yeah, I just had to keep turning it for another three minutes or so; I guess that, at least sometimes, doing the same thing over and over and expecting different results isn't *always* insanity.

Comment: Yeah, you'd already passed the insanity threshold when you got on the bike.

Comment: Did you get it off?  What was the answer?  Feel free to add your own answer and accept it.

Comment: @Criggie, [Glenn Gervais'](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/40503/how-to-remove-old-kickstand#comment-81234), [Daniel R Hicks'](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/40503/how-to-remove-old-kickstand#comment-81244) and [your comment](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/40503/how-to-remove-old-kickstand#comment-81256) were all relevant and helpful; Is it possible to create multi-author answers? ;)

Comment: I’m trying to do the same on my old bike. What exact tool did you use? Like size and everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep unscrewing (it's a standard thread) until it comes completely loose.  Typically the bolt for that style of kickstand is incredibly long, so you have to unscrew for a long time.

Comment: Accepting this as the "answer" because I've already dished out some points to the other helpful commenters ;) Anyway, I should note [that Criggie's comment above](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/40503/how-to-remove-old-kickstand#comment-81256) was quite helpful in combination with this: I sprayed some WD-40 on the bolt and that at least made the bolt more "tactile" in that I could "feel" the bolt coming out properly.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that you have stripped the bolt.  I would douse it with oil or liquid wrench, stick a screwdriver in the gap to hopefully get the bolt to bite on the next thread.  Go slow.  Aluminum strips easily if overheated.